# How to show large image in checkout page using WP Ecommerce plugin

Tags: plugin-development, images, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I want to show large image in checkout page right now it showing 31x31 size image in `wpsc-shopping_cart_page` and using `<img src="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_image(); ?>` to call thumbnail image.

what should i do for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution i find myself with just 4 easy step

```
1. go to wp ecommerce plugin folder
2. find cart.class.php file
3. find wpsc_cart_item_image function
4. change $width and $height accordingly
```

Comment: If I make the above changes - how do I ensure that it doesn;t get overwitten with an upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Goran on editing the core files. It should not be done. But, if a user has dimensions in the name of the image, they will also be replaced and the image won't display with this regular expression. Instead, you can create a new function in your theme's functions.php file. Something like this:

```
function wpsc_cart_item_image2( $width = 95, $height = 95 ) {
    global $wpsc_cart;
    $cart_image = wpsc_the_product_thumbnail( $width, $height, $wpsc_cart->cart_item->product_id, "shopping_cart");
    if( is_ssl() )
        $cart_image = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $cart_image );
    return $cart_image;
}
```

Then, make sure you copy wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php to your theme directory and replace

```
wpsc_cart_item_image();
```

with

```
wpsc_cart_item_image2();
```

Or, use a regular expression that gets the last instance of an image size.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you not to hack core files because of updates.
Rather transfer WPEC files to your theme folder and then in wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php file add following above image call

```
<?php
$imgurl = wpsc_cart_item_image();
$image = preg_replace('&(-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4})&is', '', $imgurl);
?>
```

then call original image with `<?php echo $image; ?>`

regards